# Ionic2 bind value to prompt alert

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a prompt alert in my component like following:

```
addSurveyObject(){

    let prompt = Alert.create({
      title: 'Add Survey Object',
      message: "All the fields are necessary",
      inputs: [
      {
        name: 'name',
        placeholder: 'Name'
      },
      {
        name: 'area',
        placeholder: 'Area',
        value: this.area
      },
      ],
      buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: data => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Save',
        handler: data => {

          this.createSuveyObject(data);

        }
      }
      ]
    });

    this.nav.present(prompt);
  }
```

For 'area' I want to populate it's value to a class level variable called `this.area` which get's it's value like following:

```
  calcar(shape) {
    const area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(shape.getPath());
    document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = "Area =" + area.toFixed(2);
    this.area = area;
    console.log(this.area)
    ...

    }
  }
```

This does not populate the value in the prompt alert, only string can be assigned. How I achieve this?

Comment: Which is the *type* of the `this.area` property?

Comment: it's any, but I am assigning a numeric value to it

Comment: Have you tried by adding `type: 'number'` when you set the `name`, `placeholder` and `value` properties?

Comment: I tried just now, but it just changes the input type. Value is still not populated

Comment: I've created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wK0rut?p=preview) with your code (except the part where the `this.area` is initialized) and seems to be working properly... Maybe the `this.area` property is not yet initialized when you create the `Alert`. When do you call the `calcar(...)` method?

Comment: See I updated my question with more code.

Comment: Your answer helped! I had to initialize variable in constructor.

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer in comment worked. I just modified a bit my code, as follows:

```
export class StartPage {
  private area: any;
  constructor(){
    this.area=null
   }
```

In alert:

```
{
  name: 'size',
  placeholder: 'Size',
  type: 'number',
  value: this.area
},
```